# How to set the default font for ticks in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, fonts

I am trying to set the default font for axes ticks in matplotlib. At present I set the font path:

```
path = 'palatino-regular.ttf'
prop = font_manager.FontProperties(fname=path)
```

and for each figure I have to change the tick fonts with the commands:

```
for label in ax.get_xticklabels():
    label.set_fontproperties(prop)
for label in ax.get_yticklabels():
    label.set_fontproperties(prop)
```

Is there a way to set the tick fonts globally so that I don't have to provide these commands locally for every figure I plot.

**Reproducible code**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import itertools
import matplotlib.font_manager as font_manager

path = 'palatino-regular.ttf'
prop = font_manager.FontProperties(fname=path)

m = 5
n = 5
x = np.zeros(shape=(m, n))
plt.figure(figsize=(5.15, 5.15))
plt.clf()
plt.subplot(111)
marker = itertools.cycle(('o', 'v', '^', '<', '>', 's', '8', 'p'))
ax = plt.gca()
for i in range(1, n):
    x = np.dot(i, [1, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3])
    y = x ** 2
    color = next(ax._get_lines.color_cycle)
    plt.plot(x, y, linestyle='', markeredgecolor='none', marker=marker.next(), color=color, label = str(i))
    plt.plot(x, y, linestyle='-', color = color)
plt.ylabel(r'y', labelpad=6)
plt.xlabel(r'x', labelpad=6)
for label in ax.get_xticklabels():
    label.set_fontproperties(prop)
for label in ax.get_yticklabels():
    label.set_fontproperties(prop)
plt.show()
```

I tried to set the font in matplotlibrc also, but I get the following error:

```
/opt/share/python/v2.7.9.app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py:1236: UserWarning: findfont: Font family ['palatino-regular'] not found. Falling back to Bitstream Vera Sans
  (prop.get_family(), self.defaultFamily[fontext]))
```

Comment: Have you seen [customizing matplotlob](http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html)?

Comment: In what way didn't it help?

Comment: Every time I set the font in matplotlibrc file, I get the following error:
UserWarning: findfont: Font family ['palatino-regular'] not found. Falling back to Bitstream Vera Sans
  (prop.get_family(), self.defaultFamily[fontext]))

Comment: Put that in your question.